# Paginate links with "ugly" and "pretty" permalinks?

Tags: pagination, paginate-links

If I have "pretty" permalinks enabled my code will work for static pages (will work if page is set as "home page" or "normal page" ). But my code breaks if I use "default permalink" structure.

I have this so far (working nice with "pretty permalinks" but breaks with "ugly permalinks"):

```
/*Declared above the loop*/
    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
    } elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
    } else {
    $paged = 1;
    }

    /*The loop and arguments go here*/

    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => esc_html__( 'Prev', 'domain' ),
    'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'domain' ),
    'end_size'  => 1,
    'mid_size'  => 1,
    ) );
```

Is it possible to have numbered pagination for both (ugly and pretty permalinks)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### EDIT - WORDPRESS 4.4.1 BUG

Please take note that there is a bug in WordPress 4.4.1 (*I'm not sure if this bug also influence WordPress 4.4, but according to the bug report, it does not*) which fails pagination when setting a page as static front page. Be sure to check out the bug report ([*trac ticket #35344*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35344)]) and the patch. This will be fixed in WordPress 4.4.2 according to the bug report.

### HAPPY B/DAY UPDATE/EDIT

The code I orginally did a year go only accepted the complete `WP_Query` query object which I came to realize is quite a restriction while doing [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211491/31545) (*which you can also check out*), the function needed to also accept integer/numerical values for `query` in order to page other types of queries as well

I have update the orginal code, so now you can simply pass any integer/numerical value to `query`.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

I have actually just finished a function for my own personal use yesterday as I needed something a little bit more flexible for all queries. I've decided that I needed at least 5 page numbers to be visible at all times if there were more than 5 pages. Also, I needed a link back to the first and last pages

Further more, I needed the flexibility to switch between numbered page numbers and normal paginated links. Also, the function had to be flexible so that it can be used even on static front pages.

I'm not going to go much into the operation and inner workings of the function as I have commented the most important points inside the function.

### THE FUNCTION:

```
/**
 * @author Pieter Goosen
 * @license GPLv2 
 * @link http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * This function returns numbered pagination links or text pagination links
 * depending what is been set
 *
 * Paginated numbered links uses get_pagenum_link() to return links to the
 * required pages
 * @uses http://wpseek.com/function/get_pagenum_link/
 *
 * The pagination links uses next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link()
 * @uses http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link
 * @uses http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/previous_posts_link
 *
 * @param array $args An array of key => value arguments. Defaults below 
 * - mixed query variable                   'query'                 => $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
 * - string Previous page text              'previous_page_text'    => __( '&laquo;' ),
 * - string Next page text                  'next_page_text'        => __( '&raquo;' ),
 * - string First page link text            'first_page_text'       => __( 'First' ),
 * - string Last page link text             'last_page_text'        => __( 'Last' ),
 * - string Older posts text                'next_link_text'        => __( 'Older Entries' ),
 * - string Newer posts text                'previous_link_text'    => __( 'Newer Entries' ),
 * - bool Whether to use links              'show_posts_links'      => false,
 * - int Amount of numbered links to show   'range'                 => 5,
 *
 * @return string $paginated_text
*/ 
function get_paginated_numbers( $args = [] ) {

    //Set defaults to use
    $defaults = [
        'query'                 => $GLOBALS['wp_query'],
        'previous_page_text'    => __( '&laquo;' ),
        'next_page_text'        => __( '&raquo;' ),
        'first_page_text'       => __( 'First' ),
        'last_page_text'        => __( 'Last' ),
        'next_link_text'        => __( 'Older Entries' ),
        'previous_link_text'    => __( 'Newer Entries' ),
        'show_posts_links'      => false,
        'range'                 => 5,
    ];

    // Merge default arguments with user set arguments
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    /**
     * Get current page if query is paginated and more than one page exists
     * The first page is set to 1
     * 
     * Static front pages is included
     *
     * @see WP_Query pagination parameter 'paged'
     * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters
     *
    */ 
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { 

        $current_page = get_query_var('paged'); 

    }elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { 

        $current_page = get_query_var('page'); 

    }else{ 

        $current_page = 1; 

    }

    // Get the amount of pages from the query
    if ( is_object( $args['query'] ) ) {
        $max_pages = (int) $args['query']->max_num_pages;
    } else {
        $max_pages = filter_var( $args['query'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    }

    /**
     * If $args['show_posts_links'] is set to false, numbered paginated links are returned
     * If $args['show_posts_links'] is set to true, pagination links are returned
    */
    if( false === $args['show_posts_links'] ) {

        // Don't display links if only one page exists
        if( 1 === $max_pages ) {

            $paginated_text = '';

        }else{

            /**
             * For multi-paged queries, we need to set the variable ranges which will be used to check
             * the current page against and according to that set the correct output for the paginated numbers
            */
            $mid_range      = (int) floor( $args['range'] / 2 );
            $start_range    = range( 1 , $mid_range );
            $end_range      = range( ( $max_pages - $mid_range +1 ) , $max_pages );
            $exclude        = array_merge( $start_range, $end_range );  

            /**
             * The amount of pages must now be checked against $args['range']. If the total amount of pages
             * is less than $args['range'], the numbered links must be returned as is
             *
             * If the total amount of pages is more than $args['range'], then we need to calculate the offset
             * to just return the amount of page numbers specified in $args['range']. This defaults to 5, so at any
             * given instance, there will be 5 page numbers displayed
            */
            $check_range    = ( $args['range'] > $max_pages )   ? true : false;

            if( true === $check_range ) {

                $range_numbers = range( 1, $max_pages );

            }elseif( false === $check_range ) {

                if( !in_array( $current_page, $exclude ) ) {

                    $range_numbers = range( ( $current_page - $mid_range ), ( $current_page + $mid_range ) );

                }elseif( in_array( $current_page, $start_range ) && ( $current_page - $mid_range ) <= 0 ) {

                    $range_numbers = range( 1, $args['range'] );

                }elseif(  in_array( $current_page, $end_range ) && ( $current_page + $mid_range ) >= $max_pages ) {

                    $range_numbers = range( ( $max_pages - $args['range'] +1 ), $max_pages );

                }

            }

            /**
             * The page numbers are set into an array through this foreach loop. The current page, or active page
             * gets the class 'current' assigned to it. All the other pages get the class 'inactive' assigned to it
            */
            foreach ( $range_numbers as $v ) {

                if ( $v == $current_page ) { 

                    $page_numbers[] = '<span class="current">' . $v . '</span>';

                }else{

                    $page_numbers[] = '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $v ) . '" class="inactive">' . $v . '</a>';

                }

            }

            /** 
            * All the texts are set here and when they should be displayed which will link back to:
             * - $previous_page The previous page from the current active page
             * - $next_page The next page from the current active page
             * - $first_page Links back to page number 1
             * - $last_page Links to the last page
            */
            $previous_page  = ( $current_page !== 1 )                       ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $current_page - 1 ) . '">' . $args['previous_page_text'] . '</a>' : '';
            $next_page      = ( $current_page !== $max_pages )              ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $current_page + 1 ) . '">' . $args['next_page_text'] . '</a>'     : '';
            $first_page     = ( !in_array( 1, $range_numbers ) )            ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( 1 ) . '">' . $args['first_page_text'] . '</a>'                    : '';
            $last_page      = ( !in_array( $max_pages, $range_numbers ) )   ? '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $max_pages ) . '">' . $args['last_page_text'] . '</a>'            : '';

            /**
             * Text to display before the page numbers
             * This is set to the following structure:
             * - Page X of Y
            */
            $page_text      = '<span>' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s of %s' ), $current_page, $max_pages ) . '</span>';
            // Turn the array of page numbers into a string
            $numbers_string = implode( ' ', $page_numbers );

            // The final output of the function
            $paginated_text = '<div class="pagination">';
            $paginated_text .= $page_text . $first_page . $previous_page . $numbers_string . $next_page . $last_page;
            $paginated_text .= '</div>';

        }

    }elseif( true === $args['show_posts_links'] ) {

        /**
        * If $args['show_posts_links'] is set to true, only links to the previous and next pages are displayed
        * The $max_pages parameter is already set by the function to accommodate custom queries
        */
        $paginated_text = get_next_posts_link( '<div class="next-posts-link">' . $args['next_link_text'] . '</div>', $max_pages );
        $paginated_text .= get_previous_posts_link( '<div class="previous-posts-link">' . $args['previous_link_text'] . '</div>' );

    }

    // Finally return the output text from the function
    return $paginated_text;

}
```

### USAGE

The available arguments is also well commented. Here is an example if you need to show numbered links for a custom query `$q = new WP_Query`

```
$args = [
    'query' => $q
];
echo get_paginated_numbers( $args );
```

You can simply pass custom text to the function as well if needed.

If you need to show links instead of page numbers, try the following

```
$args = [
    'query'            => $q
    'show_posts_links' => true,
];
echo get_paginated_numbers( $args );
```

With your own styling, you can have page numbers looking like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm using `show_posts_links => true` and needed to wrap the links in some custom HTML (Bootstrap-based theme). I discovered that `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` were echoing immediately, not assigning to `$paginated_text`. Changing those to `get_next_posts_link` and `get_previous_posts_link` fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

So it look's like it is possible to make this function work with “ugly” and “pretty” permalinks. Here is the code:

```
  <?php
    global $wp_query;

    //structure of "format" depends on whether we're using pretty permalinks
    if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
    $format = '?paged=%#%';
    } else {
    $format = 'page/%#%/';
    } 
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    $base = $format =='?paged=%#%' ? $base = str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ) : $base = @add_query_arg('paged','%#%');

    echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => $base,
    'format' => $format,
    'current' => max( 1, $paged ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => esc_html__( 'Prev', 'domain' ),
    'next_text' => esc_html__( 'Next', 'domain' ),
    'end_size'  => 1,
    'mid_size'  => 1,
    ) );
 ?>
```

Hope it will help someone ;)