# How to use the_posts_navigation for wp_query and get_posts?

Tags: wp-query, navigation, get-posts

WordPress have `the_posts_navigation` function since 4.1.0. But I don't know how to use with `wp_query` or `get_posts`. the following code is in a template file of page.
**wp_query method:**

```
    <?php
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $paged = get_query_var('page');
    } else {
    $paged = 1;
    }

    $get_posts=new wp_query('post_type=case&posts_per_page=2&paged='.$paged);

    while($get_posts->have_posts()):$get_posts->the_post();
    the_title();
    endwhile;

    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'cm' ),
        'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'cm' ),
        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'cm' ) . ' </span>',
    ) );
    ?>
```

**get_posts method:**

```
    <?
    while(have_posts()):the_post();
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
        $paged = 1;
    }

    $case_posts=get_posts('post_type=case&posts_per_page=2&paged='.$paged);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($case_posts);
    echo '</pre>';
    foreach($case_posts as $case_post){
        echo $case_post->post_title;
    }
    endwhile;
    // Previous/next page navigation.
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'cm' ),
        'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'cm' ),
        'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'cm' ) . ' </span>',
    ) );
    ?>
```

They don't work and display pagination, but entering http://127.0.0.1/gdboer/?page_id=74&page=2 manually in address bar, it works.
Who can help me, thank you so much!

Comment: Your question is mislead, since your code use `the_posts_pagination`, it's different with your title question `the_posts_navigation`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`the_posts_navigation()` is simply a wrapper function for [`get_the_posts_navigation()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L2233) which issimply a wrapper function for `paginate_links`. The first two functions uses the the same exact parameters that is being used by `paginate_links` and actually passes it to the latter function as well

`get_the_posts_navigation()` and `the_posts_navigation()` is good new functions as it eliminates a lot of custom coding and it is more user friendly for new unexperienced users who would like numbered pagination links

The only flaw in this `get_the_posts_navigation()` is that the developers went and wrapped the `paginate_links` function in a conditional statement that states that if the main query (`$wp_query`) has less than 1 page, (remember, the first page is `0` and the second page is `2`), don't show the links. This is problematic for custom queries on page templates. Pages will always have just one page, so these functions does not work with custom queries

The only true workaround if you have to use `the_posts_navigation()`, is to make use of @ChipBennet answer in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120408/31545). I really don't like nullifying the main query (quite hacky, in my opinion this is just like using `query_posts`) but I can't see any other solution to make `get_the_posts_navigation()` to work with custom queries

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I know the function can't to work with custom queries. By the way, you don't like nullifying the main query. But which method did you used?

Comment: I don't make use of the native function, I wrote my own pagination function which I use. You can check it out [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545)

Comment: If I use permalink like this http://127.0.0.1/gdboer/?post_type=case it didn't work. use permalink http://127.0.0.1/gdboer/?page_id=74 is OK.

Comment: I will play around with this in the coming week. Caught up in a few other things at this stage. Many thanks for your reply. This really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 9):

I have a custom template and I struggled hours to show the pagination component.
here what's worked for me.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'paged'=>$paged,
    'post_type' => 'projects'
    );

$projects = new WP_Query($args);

            <!-- working example of pagination with numbers -->
            ...<?php endwhile;?>
                <?php 
                $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $projects->max_num_pages;
                the_posts_pagination( array(
                   'mid_size' => 1,
                   'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'green' ),
                   'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'green' ),
                   'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' )
                ) ); ?>
             OR
             <!-- working example of pagination without numbers -->
             ...<?php endwhile;?>   
             <?php next_posts_link(  'next', $projects->max_num_pages ); ?>
             <?php previous_posts_link('prev') ?>
```

Comment: Definitely an idea, the only part that I don't really like is changing the main query object. It is kind of hacky and a bug that is going to give you nightmares because you do not reset the main query once you are done. Just keep that in mind. That is why globalisation is such an evil thing, anyone can change the values. Remember, many plugins rely on globals, specially `$wp_query` and `$post`

Comment: Many thanks. `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages` was the missing bit for me. Not sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 3):

This function uses the [`get_the_posts_pagination()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_posts_pagination/) which uses the GLOBAL `wp_query` to setup the `paginate_links()` function, so I believe that doesn't work for `get_posts`.

Try use the function `paginate_links()` by itself or the function `posts_nav_link()`

PS: Make sure you use `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I know paginate_links is work for me. but I want to use new function the_posts_navigation. I carefully watched get_the_posts_navigation source code, and refer to the theme of twentyfifteen.

Comment: i couldn't get `get_the_posts_pagination()` to work in my ajax query, but `paginate_links()` works fine. thanks for that.