# What is wrong with my code ? pagination does not show up

Tags: pagination

Everything works fine other than the pagination.
I have even tried with my own pagination method which works fine on Index page and Archive page but not in this template

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Flowers
 *
 */
?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php 
        echo '<hr><h2 class="post_title">Browsing : Flowers</h2><hr>';
     ?>
    <?php  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="content">
            <?php the_content();?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  ?>
    <?php  wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'category_name' => 'flowers',
        'order'         => 'asc',
        'post_type'     => 'post',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'paged'         => $paged
    ));
    if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post clearfix">
                <?php 
                echo '<div class="featured-image">';
                echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'">';
                echo the_post_thumbnail('small-thumb');
                echo '</a>';
                echo '</div>';
                ?>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <?php echo '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'.ucfirst(get_the_title()).'</a></h2>'; ?>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                    <?php
                        echo trunc(get_the_content(),25);
                        echo '<div class="continue-reading">';
                        echo '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'.__('Continue Reading', 'little-sparrow').get_the_title().'"rel="bookmark">Continue Reading <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    ?>

                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();       
    the_posts_navigation();

    ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Comment: where do you want to put the pagination ?

Comment: Sorry my code is all broken but I want the pagination to appear at the end of the loop

Comment: Just a tip, if you post code in the editor, highlight your code and click on the `{}` sign above the editor. This will add your code in a code block. Alternatively, indent your each line of code with 4 spaces

Comment: Pieter Goosen and mmm thank you very much I just joined the community yesterday.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use the\_posts\_navigation for wp\_query and get\_posts?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/how-to-use-the-posts-navigation-for-wp-query-and-get-posts)

Comment: @PieterGoosen 

when I query as follows the pagination shows up but the problem is that it is showing the same result again and again even when /paged/10 
 query_posts(array(
     'category_name' => 'flowers',
     'orderby'   => 'desc',
     'post_status'  => 'publish'
    ));

Comment: You should **never ever** use `query_posts`. It breaks the main query object. I have linked to a post inside the marked duplicate from Chip Bennet. Did you try that method

Comment: @PieterGoosen I found a way that works with query_post but you are right it breaks the loop at some point. And yes I did try as your link suggest but still the navigation does not show up.

Comment: I will post a solution much later as I'm at work and posting from my mobile. :-)