# Pagination of custom page with custom fields query

Tags: wp-query, query, pagination

Hello I have created a custom php file that I use to show specific posts by value inside the a custom field. So for example I have 100 posts, let's say they all have custom field MyTitle and 10 of them have value "New".

```
$querystr = "
            SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
            FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
            WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'Mytitle' 
            AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$mytitle."%' 
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
            AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
            ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
         ";

         $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

So I use the code to display those posts, however I wanted to add a pagination.I've done some search here and on the internet, but all the pagination is rather different talking about getting "paged" from the main query.. I don't really understand that part. So can you show me examples which I can use with the code that I've shown here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with this, never pass raw variables to a sql query! unless you have 100% control over the variable content, and even then I would still not pass it raw.
Always [use prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Now going by your need you will need to do something like this

```php
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var( 'paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$posts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_key'       => 'Mytitle',
    'meta_value'     => $mytitle,
    'meta_compare'   => 'LIKE',
    'paged'          => $paged
]);
?>

<ul>

<?php if ($posts->have_posts()) : while ($posts->have_posts()) : $posts->the_post(); ?>
<li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php
endwhile; endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>

</ul>

<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links([
            'base'         => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link(999999999))),
            'total'        => $posts->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var('paged')),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf('<i></i> %1$s', __('Newer Posts', 'text-domain')),
            'next_text'    => sprintf('%1$s <i></i>', __('Older Posts', 'text-domain')),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ]);
    ?>
</div>
```

This is a very raw example so you will need to do changes based on your needs.

Some resources to get a better idea on how everything works.

1. [WP_Query class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)
2. [Looping WP_Query](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mastering-wp_query-using-the-loop--cms-23031)
3. [Pagination with WP_Query WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query)
4. [Wordpress pagination codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

Comment: I actually check for specific contents - only,  of the variable value from the URL before passing it to the sql query. However I will try your example.

Comment: The code is working, showing the results and links, however the links are not working.I believe this is because I have used a custom rewrite rule in my functions.php file so that theurl works something like : website/mycustomphppage/new/
so the link now is website/mycustomphppage/new/page/2/ 

add_rewrite_rule( 'mycustomphppage/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=mycustomphppage&mytitle=$matches[1]', 'top');

Do you have any advice how to add the pagination to this rule?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Im not that good with rewrite rules to tell you what causes this issue, maybe @MrWhite could help out, he has a loads of experience with rewrites so, if he sees this post, maybe he could shed some light on this issue =].

Comment: @WordpressGuest I have found [this](https://www.grzegorowski.com/wordpress-rewrite-rules) article that talks about pagination with rewrite rules, maybe that could give you more information.

Comment: I have managed to make it work, first it did not work as I was trying to look for page query var, when the page query var is named paged , so this works(added another rule):
add_rewrite_rule( 'mycustomphppage/(.+?)/page/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=mycustomphppage&mytitle=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');