# the_posts_pagination() not working in wpquery

Tags: php, wp-query, pagination

I'm trying to create pagination to the custom wp_query here is my code:

```
<?php
    $btpgid=get_queried_object_id();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    $args = array( 
        'cat' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 6, 
        'paged' => $paged,
        'post_type' => 'post' 
    );
    $postslist = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $postslist->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $postslist->have_posts() ) : $postslist->the_post(); ?>
                                            
                                            
            <div class="col-lg-6 right-padding m-t-50">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?> " title="" class="case-box blog-box" data-aos="flip-left">
                    <span class="green-filter case-image-holder">
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
                    </span>
                    <span class="content">
                        <span class="blog-box-title">
                           <?php echo the_title(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <p class="section-p"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                </a>
            </div>

        <?php endwhile;  ?>
    <div class="pagination d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-100 m-t-50">
        <?php 
            next_posts_link( '< Starsze posty', $postslist->max_num_pages );
            previous_posts_link( 'Nowsze posty >' ); 
            wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It all works fine when i'm using only "previous" and "next" site pagination like so:

```
<?php 
    next_posts_link( '< Starsze posty', $postslist->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Nowsze posty >' ); 
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

But when i'm trying to use numbered pagination - it displays nothing - like that:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) ); ?>
```

Do i have some mistakes in the code? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to wpse! take a look at [Pagination when using wp_query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query). It looks like you are missing some properties in the array thats being passed to the `the_posts_pagination`. You can use the complete answer in the link or just copy the array, just change the properties accordingly.

Comment: Thank you - works like a charm!

Comment: Consider added your working code as a answer so future users that encounter the same problem can your answer to help them out.

Comment: Sure already did that - thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Buttered_Toast i've managed to get it work by changing:

```
<?php the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size'  => 2,
    'prev_text' => __( 'Back', 'textdomain' ),
    'next_text' => __( 'Onward', 'textdomain' ),
) ); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php  echo paginate_links( array(
    'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
    'total'        => $postslist->max_num_pages,
    'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
    'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
    'show_all'     => false,
    'type'         => 'plain',
    'end_size'     => 2,
    'mid_size'     => 1,
    'prev_next'    => true,
    'prev_text'    => sprintf(  __( '<', 'text-domain' ) ),
    'next_text'    => sprintf(  __( '>', 'text-domain' ) ),
    'add_args'     => false,
    'add_fragment' => '',
    ) );
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```