# Wordpress database html table with pagination

Tags: php

I know how to display the WordPress database table with Foreach loop, but I want to add pagination to the output HTML table so that it should show only the first 100 results then I can use pagination options for further output (if I can use something like `$xrd_match = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM xrd_data_match LIMIT $next, 10" );`).

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$xrd_match = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM xrd_data_match" );
foreach ( $xrd_match as $print )   {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $print->order_id;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->match1;?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
```

Comment: Check [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query), not sure why you run a sql query instead of using the built in functions/classes to get DB data. I would suggest reading about those first before you start running sql queries

Comment: Sir, will this default wordpress fucntion `paginate_links()` work for custom wordpress database table, because this is not a post table?

Comment: If you plan on using a custom DB table you would need to create your own pagination. My question is why create a custom table in the first place? using custom post types/taxonomies cannot give you the solution you are looking for? You could also use ACF to add adittional input fields to add as much custom data as you need

Comment: Sir, this is no way related to posts. This is some custom WordPress database table created for woocommerce orders custom data.