# Pagination not working only on Archive-Name.php using new WP_Query

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, custom-post-type-archives, sticky-post, archive-template

I created an archive-sticky.php where I added the code below to show all sticky posts in one single page with pagination as there will be 100s of sticky posts in the coming days.

Now, this code displays the content as it should but the pagination is not showing/working. Where am I going wrong? I have read up 10s of queries here but nothing seems to solve my problem.

The pagination is working for other pages though.

```
<?php get_header(); 
/*
Template Name: Archives Sticky
*/
?>
<?php 
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'orderby'     => 'post_date',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'post__in'  => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
)); 
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Sticky Featured posts</h2>
            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
                    pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
                } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here's how the functions.php looks like:

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{
    $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
 
    global $paged;
    if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;
 
    if($pages == '')
    {
        global $wp_query;
        $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
        if(!$pages)
        {
            $pages = 1;
        }
    }
 
    if(1 != $pages)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
        if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
        if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";
 
        for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
        {
            if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
            {
                echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
            }
        }
 
        if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";
        if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination when using wp\_query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query)

Comment: I already tried this. All I got is `<div class="pagination"> </div>`

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried that just returned that element?

Comment: I tried both the solutions submitted by @Dave Romsey mentioned in your link. I removed my code and replaced it with his.

Comment: Did you also change the variable that contains the instance of `WP_Query`? you have a variable named `$the_query`, they have `$query`. Also notice that they use paged property in the array that is being passed into WP_Query

Comment: OMG!! I didn't notice the `$the_query`. Replacing that worked. Thank you so much. Please have it as an answer So i can marked this as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this SO question [Pagination when using wp_query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254199/pagination-when-using-wp-query)

Notice that their example uses the `$query` variable for the `WP_Query` instance, while your code uses `$the_query`.
Also notice that they use paged property in the array that is being passed into WP_Query