# Filter CPT posts by one or more categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to filter the posts on a CPT by one or more categories.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'cpt-name',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
);

// cat_term_id have been registered as a custom query var
$categories = get_query_var( "cat_term_id" );

if ( !empty( $categories ) ) {    
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'          => 'category',
            'field'             => 'term_id',
            'terms'             => $categories,
            'include_children'  => false,
        ),
    );
}

$filtered_posts = get_posts( args );
```

The query works, the problem is that is bringing all the posts on the CPT, and what I want is to only get the posts using the categories passed by `cat_term_id`.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the query was working as expected.

The problem was that with the pagination call:

```
the_posts_pagination(array(
    'screen_reader_text' => 'Navigation',
    'prev_text'          => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" ></i>',
    'next_text'          => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" ></i>',
));
```

From reading the code and finding [this question on StackOverflow](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174907/how-to-use-the-posts-navigation-for-wp-query-and-get-posts), I discovered that the function `the_posts_pagination` is a wrapper for the function `get_the_posts_navigation` which uses `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages` to know the number of pages to paginate. And because I'm using a custom query, my pagination was out of context.

I hope this helps someone.