# paginate_links() Change the order of links

Tags: filters, order, paginate-links

While using `paginate_links()` function of WordPress, i need to change the order in which it echo's its output. For example, by default it will output pagination links in this format:

**Default Output:**

```
<<PREV 1 2 3  NEXT>>
```

But i need its output in following format:

**Required Output:**

```
1 2 3 <<PREV NEXT>>
```

Now, the question is, how to change the order of these pagination links as per my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with the default [`paginate_links()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) functions. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2533), there are no filters from which you can change the layout as you wish

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTIONS

Although you cannot do this by default, it doesn't mean that you cannot get your desired output. Here is a couple of options to explore

### OPTION 1

Write a wrapper function for `paginate_links()` and set `prev_next` to `false`

You can then use [`get_next_post_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_next_post_link/) and [`get_previous_post_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_previous_post_link/) to display the next and previous post link text ( `<<PREV NEXT>>`)

Try something line this: (*CAVEAT: Untested, might be buggy*)

```
function my_paginate_links() {

    $args = array( //Add arguments as needed
        'prev_next'    => false,
    );

    $number_link = paginate_links( $args );

    $previous = get_previous_posts_link( '<<PREV ' );
    $next = get_next_posts_link( ' NEXT>>' );

    $link = $number_link . $previous . $next;

    return $link;

}
```

In your template file, just use it as

```
echo my_paginate_links();
```

### OPTION 2

If option 1 fails, you can copy the `paginate_links()` function to your theme, rename it, and modify the source code as needed to get the desired output

### OPTION 3

Write your own function to get the desired output. For a little inspiration, check out [this custom function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545) I have recently done in another answer on this site. Use and abuse it as you see fit.