# Main page paginate_links issue

Tags: pagination

So, I found out what the problem is with the frontpage pagination issue.

i have woocommerce products listed on a main page which has pagination.

However, it was repeating the first page.

I changed the static page (Front page) to something else, then the pagination problem is gone.

So it looks like there is a pagination problem with the static front page.

How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I have written a custom function in an answer to elimanate problems with custom queries and static front pages, I will just need to look for it :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! this problem has been bugging me for last a week, and that will be super awesome! :D

Comment: Ha, found it! Check it out [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545). Just a note, it requires PHP 5.4+. If you need to use it on older versions, you have to change the new array syntax (`[]`) back to the old syntax (`array()`)

Comment: Haha Awesome! Thanks Pieter! =DD I will check it out right now! =)