# Complex query and posts pagination

Tags: loop, pagination

I have this complex posts query, but I cant get the page navigation to work, been trying for hours with no luck, what am i missing?

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('recipe','post'),
    'posts_per_page'  => 30,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'condition',
         'terms' => $arrArea1,
         'field' => 'slug'
       ),      
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'diet_type',
         'terms' => 'High Fiber',
         'field' => 'slug'
       ),          
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>  
<div class="postCont">   
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <h2>What's Fresh</h2>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'profile-subscriber' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php else:  ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>              
</div>
```

I need to figure this out so I can do some ajax load more post actions, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `post_nav_link()` function is used to paginate the main query on home and archive pages. It does not work with custom queries (*unless you hack the main query which I strongly discourage, it is the same as using `query_posts` then*).

To paginate your custom query, you need to use

- [`next_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link)
- [`previous_posts_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_posts_link)

which will echo the links. If you need it returned, just use their `get_*` counterparts. There is a nice example of how to paginate a custom query on the `next_posts_link()` codex page.

I have also written a custom pagination function which work with any query and either display pagination as links or as numbers. You can check it out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545)

If you are going to using ajax for infinite scrolling, there are quite a few plugins (*and tutorials IIRC*) to check out and from which you can 'borrow' some code. Just make sure, I have seen one or two plugins/tutorials that uses `query_posts`. You should avoid using those as you should never ever use `query_posts` as it breaks/hacks the main query object.

One last note, I'm not sure where you would want to use the query, but static frontpages make use of `get_query_var( 'page' )` and not `get_query_var( 'paged' )`, so if you are using the query on a static front page, make sure to change accordingly